# Meaning and nuance of "The art of those commercials is not to be mean, but it’s actually for the guys to like each other."

Tags: meaning, connotations

I love this part of the interview of Steve Jobs and Bill Gates because they, have been long-time rival to each other, exchanged positive emotions between them, on Steve's explaining about Apple's famous CM, Mac Guy vs PC Guy.

Then, I hope to understand the difference of a meaning or a nuance of the following sentences. I cannot get why Steve used the word "to".

An original sentence is:
*The art of those commercials is not to be mean, but it’s actually for the guys to like each other.*

Why would it not be "The art of those commercials is not mean, but it’s actually for the guys who like each other."?

[Steve Jobs and Bill Gates Together at D5 Conference 2007](https://youtu.be/wvhW8cp15tk?t=1489)

Here is the transcript. 
**Kara:** And do you look at yourselves as rivals now? Today as the landscape has evolved–and we’ll talk about the Internet landscape and everything else and other companies that have [gone] forward, but how do you look at yourselves in this landscape today?
**Walt:** Because, I mean, you are competitors in certain ways, which is the American way, right?
**Kara:** We watch the commercials, right?
**Walt:** And you get annoyed at each other from time to time.
**Kara:** Although you know what? I have to confess, I like PC guy.
**Walt:** Yeah, he’s great.
**Kara:** Yeah, I like him. The young guy, I want to pop him.
**Steve:** *The art of those commercials is not to be mean, but it’s actually for the guys to like each other.* Thanks. PC guy is great. Got a big heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jobs is not saying "the art is not mean", he's saying (badly!) that the [art](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/art) *of the commercial* is *in* not being mean.  I would paraphrase his sentence like this:

> The skillfulness of those commercials is demonstrated not in being mean, but in these two guys liking each other.

But his sentence is not very well-formed, which makes it harder to understand what he was saying.  (Steve Jobs was a charismatic and engaging public speaker, but he was not very precise when he was speaking [off the cuff](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-cuff).)